# Populate Nested ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wcf, generic-collections

I have a class

```
public class Owner
{
public int OwnerId{get; set;}
public int OwnerName{get; set;}
public ObservableCollection<Owner> SubOwner{get; set;}
}
```

The data returned from DB is

```
Owner_Id           Owner_Parent_Id

1                       null

2                        1

3                        1

4                        3

5                        3

6                        4

7                        6
```

I need to populate my variable ObservableCollection Owner with above data(like tree structure).Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to learn how to build a non-binary tree from the owner ID and owner parent ID that you are getting from the database.  To do this, you need to keep track of the tree root (an instance of Owner) separarely.  You then add an API to add a new Owner to your tree that is only called on the tree root.  This API walks the tree recursively until it finds the correct parent to add to.  You can also arrange your tree so that it's faster than having to search every node.

Here's a good [tutorial](http://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/treet-implementing-a-non-binary-tree-in-c/) on creating a tree in C#.

**However**, in your simple example above, I would not recommend a tree.  I'd recommend adding the parentID to your Owner class and then using a simple SortedList<int ID, Owner>.  Then you can easily find an ID, get its parent, and traverse *as if* you had a tree.  For example:

```
void WalkUpTree(SortedList<int, Owner> tree, Owner node)
{
    // (do something with node)

    // process parent
    if (node.parentID == 0 || tree.ContainsKey(node.parentID) == false)
        return;    // No parent
    WalkUpTree(tree, tree[node.parentID]);
}
```

If you want to walk *down* the tree, keep the index of the root node, and then make a second SortedList<int, Owner> where the int is parent ID rather than ID.  WalkUpTree then becomes WalkDownTree using the second SortedList.